# Converting data from one to other format

Tags: r, dplyr

I working with a data set that contains numbers stored as characters. Below you can see data example of data extracted with the dput function:

```
structure(list(Y_O_13_Males = c("10", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), Y_O_13_Females = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y_O_13_Unknown = c("7", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y14_17_Males = c("2", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y14_17_Females = c("0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y14_17_Unknown = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y18_34_Males = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y18_34_Females = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y18_34_Unknown = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y35_64_Males = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y35_64_Females = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y35_64_Unknown = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y65_And_Over_Males = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y65_And_Over_Females = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Y65_And_Over_Unknown = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Unknown_And_Over_Males = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Unknown_And_Over_Females = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Unknown_And_Over_Unknown = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to convert all of this data from character format to numeric.I tryed with this line of code but is not working.

```
 df[,1:18]<-as.numeric(df[,1:18])
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: as.data.frame(sapply(dt, as.numeric)) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, I would use:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(
        across(
            .cols = where(is.character), 
            .fns = as.numeric
        )
    )
```

That also assumes that you want to change to numeric ALL character variables.

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply it, i.e.

```
df[1:18]<-lapply(df[1:18], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try `type.convert` like below

```
> type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 10 × 18
   Y_O_13_Males Y_O_13_Females Y_O_13_Unknown Y14_17_Males Y14_17_Females
          <int>          <int>          <int>        <int>          <int>
 1           10              1              7            2              0
 2            0              0              0            0              0
 3            0              0              0            0              0
 4            0              0              0            0              0
 5            0              0              0            0              0
 6            0              0              0            0              0
 7            0              0              0            0              0
 8            0              0              0            0              0
 9            0              0              0            0              0
10            0              0              0            0              0
# … with 13 more variables: Y14_17_Unknown <int>, Y18_34_Males <int>,
#   Y18_34_Females <int>, Y18_34_Unknown <int>, Y35_64_Males <int>,
#   Y35_64_Females <int>, Y35_64_Unknown <int>, Y65_And_Over_Males <int>,
#   Y65_And_Over_Females <int>, Y65_And_Over_Unknown <int>,
#   Unknown_And_Over_Males <int>, Unknown_And_Over_Females <int>,
#   Unknown_And_Over_Unknown <int>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple base R assuming you only have those 18 columns:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 2):

The class can be changed from `character` to `numeric` with:

```
for(i in which(sapply(df, class) == "character")) class(df[[i]]) <- "numeric"

str(df)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       10 obs. of  18 variables:
# $ Y_O_13_Males            : num  10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y_O_13_Females          : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y_O_13_Unknown          : num  7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y14_17_Males            : num  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y14_17_Females          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y14_17_Unknown          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y18_34_Males            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y18_34_Females          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y18_34_Unknown          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y35_64_Males            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y35_64_Females          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y35_64_Unknown          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y65_And_Over_Males      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y65_And_Over_Females    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Y65_And_Over_Unknown    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Unknown_And_Over_Males  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Unknown_And_Over_Females: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ Unknown_And_Over_Unknown: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In this case `integer` might fit better than `numeric`.